# How can I disable Jetpack plugin on mobile?

Tags: plugins, gallery, responsive, plugin-jetpack

I'm using the Wordpress jetpack plugin to create a gallery on a WP site. However I want to disable it completely based on the visitors viewport, how can I achieve this?

Comment: doesn't really sound feasible, since jetpack is loading server-side which loads first and mobile viewport is client-side which loads after... so you can't retroactively unload all of jetpack... that said you might be able to unload it's stylesheets or javascript using javascript, but it might be easier to find a gallery plugin that can handle mobile the way you want.

Comment: you want to disable jetpack or this gallery output?

Comment: @hwl I'd like disable to gallery output at a certain viewport.

Comment: @majick Thanks for the comment, thinking the same.